# Python Help | Read data from text file from the bottom

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Can someone have a look at my program? There's an error which I cannot identify and it's really confusing me. Also, please explain to me the problem so that I can understand how to use the function and program in another situation.

```
input_name = input("\nPlease enter students name » ").strip()
datafile = '1.txt'

while open(datafile, 'r') as f:
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.split('=')
        name = name.strip
        value = str(value)
        data.setdefault(name, []).append(value)
else:
    break
avg = {}
for name, scores in data.items():
    last_scores = scores[-3:]
    avg[name] = sum(last_scores) / len(last_scores)

print("\n", input_name,"'s average score is", avg(input_name))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Single steps

Read all data into a dict:

```
data = {}
for line in f:
    name, value = line.split('=')
    name = name.strip()
    value = int(value)
    data.setdefault(name, []).append(value)
```

The content of `data`:

```
{'Chris': [9, 9],
 'John': [6, 4, 5],
 'Sarah': [4, 7],
 'Tanzil': [4, 4, 10, 5, 3],
 'Tom': [2]}
```

Now you can calculate the average:

```
last_scores = data['Tanzil'][-3:]
avg = sum(last_scores) / len(last_scores)


>>> avg
6.0
```

or averages for all:

```
avg = {}
for name, scores in data.items():
    last_scores = scores[-3:]
    avg[name] = sum(last_scores) / len(last_scores)
```

now `avg` holds:

```
{'Chris': 9.0, 'John': 5.0, 'Sarah': 5.5, 'Tanzil': 6.0, 'Tom': 2.0}
```

Show all results:

```
for name, value in avg.items():
    print(name, value)
```

prints:

```
Tanzil 6.0
Chris 9.0
Sarah 5.5
John 5.0
Tom 2.0
```

or nicely ordered highest to lowest average score:

```
from operator import  itemgetter

for name, value in sorted(avg.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        print(name, value)
```

prints:

```
Chris 9.0
Tanzil 6.0
Sarah 5.5
John 5.0
Tom 2.0
```

### Full program

```
input_name = input("\nPlease enter students name » ").strip()
datafile = '1.txt'

with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.split('=')
        name = name.strip()
        value = int(value)
        data.setdefault(name, []).append(value)

avg = {}
for name, scores in data.items():
    last_scores = scores[-3:]
    avg[name] = sum(last_scores) / len(last_scores)

print("\n", input_name,"'s average score is", avg[input_name])
```

Comment: How would I have it so it outputs each users results under each other not next to each other in a row.?

Comment: Just loop through the dict. Updated my answer.

Comment: After the results of all of the users are in order down a list. Is there an easy way to output the highest users average to lowest user?

Comment: Last addition to this answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
with open('demo.txt','r') as f:
    reversedList=reversed(f.read().splitlines())
    print filter(lambda x:'Tanzil' in x,reversedList)[:3]
```

Output:

```
['Tanzil = 3', 'Tanzil = 5', 'Tanzil = 10']
```

Comment: I don't want it neccasarily want it just for 'tanzil', I want it for any name inputted under variable 'name'

Comment: It will work for any variable. Just replace the variable name with `'Tanzil'`, that's it. You can make a function that takes a name and returns the list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following would help you perform your task:

- Initialize counter and sum as 0, and read file in **reversed** order
- Split the line and check if first part is the **required named**. If true, get the second part, and add it to the sum and increment the counter
- When counter hits 3, break the loop
- Print the average after dividing sum by 3

  ```
  counter, sumTotal = 0, 0
  for line in reversed(open("1.txt").readlines()):
    splitArray = line.split("=")
    if splitArray[0].strip() == name:
      sumTotal = sumTotal + int(splitArray[1].strip())
      counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 3:
      break

  if counter == 3:
    print "Average for {0} = {1}".format(name, sumTotal/3)
  else if counter == 0:
    print "Name {0} not found".format(name)
  else:
    print "Name {0} does not have three scores".format(name)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux box you can use `tac` (cat backwards) - concatenate and print files in reverse.

```
>>> import os
>>> for line in os.popen('tac 1.txt'):
...  do you existing processing here
```